# Pagination In RDL

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I am facing the pagination issues in RDL generation. My report is showing 7 pages in RDL but actually the records are coming upto 4 pages. 5th, 6th and 7th pages are coming blank.

I have done some research and found that there is a property "pagebreak" is use to give the pagination in RDL. Currently I have set the this property to "None" in my RDL. I changed this property to given options but still my issue have not resolved. Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happened to me once because there was an entity just hanging over too far on the right.  Try ensuring all your objects are within the bounds of an 8.5x11 page.

Comment: Just to add to comment above - within the bound INCLUDING margins.

Comment: I have checked my Report Properties and the interactive size is WIDTH: 8.5in and HEIGHT: 11in. Margins are 1in,1in,1in,1in. Everything is set fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments above. Actually I have given the extra height in my Reports which cause the report to expand to extra pages even after the completion of result set. I just reduced the height to 0pt and now it's working fine.